# Unable to put outlet output in css grid

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to create a simple layout of header sidebar and mainscreen in react and have tried everything to bring the outlet in the mainscreen component but it always has block scope at the end of the page

working sandboxlink https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-sanne-mncm97

my react routes

```
<>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Layout />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="home" element={<Home />}>
            <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route path="sales" element={<Sales />} />
            <Route path="inventory" element={<Inventory />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path="sales" element={<Sales />} />
          <Route path="one" element={<One />} />
          <Route path="finance" element={<Finance />} />
          <Route path="team" element={<Team />} />
          <Route path="settings" element={<Settings />} />
          <Route path="support" element={<Support />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
```

My layout page

```
<div>
      <div
        className="container"
        style={{
          display: "grid",
          gridAutoFlow: "row dense",
          gridTemplateColumns: "0.7fr 1.3fr 1fr",
          gridTemplateRows: "0.3fr 1.7fr 1fr",
          gap: "0px 0px",
          gridTemplateAreas:
            '"header header header"\n    "sidebar Mainscreen Mainscreen"\n    "sidebar Mainscreen Mainscreen"\n',
        }}
      >
        <div
          className="header"
          style={{ gridArea: "header", textAlign: "center" }}
        >
          <h1>Header here</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="sidebar" style={{ gridArea: "sidebar" }}>
          <Sidebarz />
        </div>
        <div
          className="Mainscreen"
          style={{
            gridArea: "Mainscreen",
            textAlign: "center",
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <Home />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My home

```
<div>
      This text gets centred in the Mainscreen area
      {/* outlet gets printed at bottom */}
      <Outlet />
    </div>
```

The output i want:

[image: the output i want]

The output I am getting with router component at bottom of page
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The `Layout` component is rendering the sidebar and "Mainscreen" div element and the `Routes` and `Routes` are rendered below it.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Layout /> // <-- layout here
        <Routes> // <-- routes under it
          <Route path="home" element={<Home />}>
            <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route path="sales" element={<Sales />} />
            <Route path="inventory" element={<Inventory />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Solution

The `Layout` component needs to render an `Outlet` ***and*** be rendered as a layout route.

```
import React from "react";
import { Sidebarz } from "./Components/Sidebar";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

export const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className="container"
        style={{
          display: "grid",
          gridAutoFlow: "row dense",
          gridTemplateColumns: "0.7fr 1.3fr 1fr",
          gridTemplateRows: "0.3fr 1.7fr 1fr",
          gap: "0px 0px",
          gridTemplateAreas:
            '"header header header"\n    "sidebar Mainscreen Mainscreen"\n    "sidebar Mainscreen Mainscreen"\n'
        }}
      >
        <div
          className="header"
          style={{ gridArea: "header", textAlign: "center" }}
        >
          <h1>Header here</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="sidebar" style={{ gridArea: "sidebar" }}>
          <Sidebarz />
        </div>
        <div
          className="Mainscreen"
          style={{
            gridArea: "Mainscreen",
            textAlign: "center",
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center"
          }}
        >
          <Outlet /> // <-- Outlet for nested routes
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<Layout />}> // <-- layout route
            <Route path="home" element={<Home />}>
              <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
              <Route path="sales" element={<Sales />} />
              <Route path="inventory" element={<Inventory />} />
            </Route>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit unable-to-put-outlet-output-in-css-grid]